# Pass JSON data to multiple activities

Tags: android, json

I have an app with a log in form and after log in, user can view his data on multiple activities. Data is on online SQL Server.

I made log in work, and now want to show data on my all activities using JSON parsing.

Comment: I do not understand your problem actually. Is it request and parse json data or how to store data and show it in activities ?

Comment: i want to bring data from server and show it on multiple activities

Comment: Be specific in your question in order to get an specific answer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: Secondary to [How to pass data between Activities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-on-android).

Answer (score 0):

First checkout how sending request in android. This library is the google created and easy to implement.
https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html

Secondly you should figure out how to store your data. In database or in memory. You should checkout java singleton pattern or sqlite database in android.

Comment: my data is on online sql server and i made log in checking throgh http post and request and backend services

Comment: but now i want to show data of server in multiple activities ?